# Compose functions with function operators does not work as expected

Tags: r, functional-programming, pryr

In the following example I created the `add_timing` function operator. The input is a function (say `mean`) and it returns a function that does the same as `mean`, but reports on how long it took for the function to complete. See the following example:

```
library(pryr)

add_timing = function(input_function, specific_info) {
  if (missing(specific_info)) specific_info = function(l) 'That'
  function(...) {
    relevant_value = specific_info(list(...))
    start_time = Sys.time()
    res = input_function(...)
    cat(sprintf('%s took', relevant_value), difftime(Sys.time(), start_time, units = 'secs'), 'sec', '\n')
    res
  }
}
timed_mean = add_timing(mean)
# > timed_mean(runif(10000000))
# That took 0.4284899 sec 
# [1] 0.4999762
```

Next I tried to use `pryr::compose` to create the same `timed_mean` function (I like the syntax):

```
timed_mean_composed = pryr::compose(add_timing, mean)
```

But this does get me the required output:

```
# > timed_mean_composed(runif(100))
# function(...) {
#        relevant_value = specific_info(list(...))
#        start_time = Sys.time()
#        res = input_function(...)
#        cat(sprintf('%s took', relevant_value), difftime(Sys.time(), start_time, units = 'secs'), 'sec', '\n')
#        res
#      }
```

It seems that the compose operation does not lead to the `add_timing` function actually being executed. Only after calling the function, the new `timed_mean_compose` actually shows the correct function output.

Based on the [following example](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Function-operators.html#combining-fos) from Advanced R by @HadleyWickham I expected this to work as I used it (see below for an excerpt):

```
dot_every <- function(n, f) {
  i <- 1
  function(...) {
    if (i %% n == 0) cat(".")
    i <<- i + 1
    f(...)
  }
}
download <- pryr::compose(
  partial(dot_every, 10),
  memoise,
  partial(delay_by, 1),
  download_file
)
```

Where the `dot_every` function operator is used in the same way I use `add_timing` above.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that in your first attempt, you are calling

```
(add_timing(mean))(runif(1e7)
```

and with the `compose` syntax you are calling something more similar to

```
add_timing(mean(runif(1e7))
```

These are not exactly equivalent. Actually, the `pryr` compose function is really expanding the syntax to something more like

```
x <- runif(1e7)
x <- mean(x)
x <- add_timing(x)
```

Maybe looking at this will help

```
a <- function(x) {print(paste("a:", x));x}
b <- function(x) {print(paste("b:", x));x}
x <- pryr::compose(a,b)(print("c"))
# [1] "c"
# [1] "b: c"
# [1] "a: c"
```

Notice how `a` isn't called until after `b`. This means that `a` would have no way to time `b`. `compose` would not be an appropriate way to create a timer wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `pryr::compose` is aimed at doing something completely different from what you're trying to do in your initial example. You want to create a function factory (called `add_timing`), which will take a function as input and return a new function as output that does the same thing as the input function but with an additional time printing. I would write that as follows:

```
add_timing <- function(FUN) { function(...) { print(system.time(r <- FUN(...))); r }}
mean(1:5)
# [1] 3
add_timing(mean)(1:5)
#    user  system elapsed 
#       0       0       0 
# [1] 3
```

The `compose` function, by contrast, returns a function that represents a series of functions to be evaluated in sequence. The examples in `? compose` are helpful here. Here's an example that builds on that:

```
add1 <- function(x) x + 1
times2 <- function(x) x * 2

# the following two are identical:
add1(1)
# [1] 2
compose(add1)(1)
# [1] 2

# the following two are identical:
times2(1) 
# [1] 2
compose(times2)(1)
# [1] 2
```

`compose` becomes useful for nesting, when the order of nesting is important:

```
add1(times2(2))
# [1] 5
compose(add1, times2)(2)
# [1] 5

times2(add1(2))
# [1] 6
compose(times2, add1)(2)
# [1] 6
```

This means that the reason your example does not work is because your functions are not actually nested in the way that `compose` is intended to work. In your example, you're asking `system.time` to, for example, calculate the time to evaluate `3` (the output of `mean`) rather than the time to evaluate `mean(1:5)`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. My question is then why the `dot_every` function factory does work, and mine does not.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I think I would stay away from the `dot_every` example here because there's a lot going on given the use of `partial` and the fact that `dot_every` is using assignment into a function's environment. It is rather obscure; as an example, run: `f <- dot_every(3, mean); environment(f)$i; f(1); f(1); f(1); environment(f)$i`